# Relocating to a new city for postdoc when you have a partner

Tags: postdocs, australia, two-body-problem

I recently applied and interviewed for a post doc position in a leading scientific institution in Australia.
I never thought I'd get the position, and the reason why I interviewed was to get more experience in speaking up. However, I got the position, and now I'm really conflicted as if I should take it.

If I accept, I'd work on an amazing project, I actually really like the project and it has everything to do with me. But I'd have to relocate. The position is for three years.

I live a very balanced life with my partner (we live together), in the town where all his family and friends live in a different Australian state. I'm not from Australia.

I've been thinking about this and if we move he'll suffer the most and I'm pretty sure it would degrade the relationship. He'll hate me for making him move, and will probably resent me. We spoke about this and he's really reluctant of going, in general he's very resistant to change, while I'm the opposite...

But then I say to myself - no, I will not accept the position because it's the best for the relationship, then I start getting upset with everything because I sort of want that particular postdoc, and I'm scared I will be the one who becomes resentful. I know that If I was alone I'd go tomorrow.

I know that academia is full of relocation problems, I'd love to hear any similar stories and what happened. Anyone out there that has gone through something similar? I'd love to hear your stories and what happened.

Comment: If you cannot relocate, then you are almost certain to have to leave academia.  (Then again, in most fields, you are still pretty likely to have to leave academia in any case.)  Australians have it tougher because in many cases they have to be willing to relocate more than 24 hours of flying away.

Comment: @AzorAhai it sounds like OP lives in one of the six Australian states, and the postdoc is in another.

Comment: @Azor Ahai yes, we live in an Australian state, but we'd have to relocate to another state for this position.

Comment: I ask because as Alexander points out - you could be bringing up moving to the States. Since you already live in Australia you're not moving *that far* - Sydney to Perth is only a five hour flight (ofc there could be time getting to/from towns). I want to echo einpokulum's comments about women turning down two-body problems more than men. I hope you can work it out, but if he's not willing to move within the same country for you ...

Comment: You may want to rephrase your last paragraph. We are a Q&A site; posts asking for "stories" will be closed (how would we vote for the "best" story)? But if you want to know "what factors to consider" or something "answerable" like that, we may be able to help.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who spent time answering or commenting this thread! @cag51 you can feel free to close this

Comment: This private part of the story can be a big problem for us willing to stay in academia. You cannot get an answer here. I myself, I have suffered a lot from similar situations, even with different partners. It is hard not being settled until a certain age.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've asked for stories about this problem from others, I'm going to give a second answer here telling you about my own circumstances and career.  I had my first two daughters when I was very young, and I was raising them while I was a university student.  By the time I graduated and was looking for academic positions, I was pretty-well locked into a single city where my children were settled in at school and everyone else in my life is present.  So mine was more of a "four-body problem" (or maybe even more) than a two-body problem.

I made the decision that I would stay in my own city and restrict my academic career options to my local universities.  (Fortunately for me, there are two good research universities with campuses in my city.)  I have been reasonably successful in this, and I have managed to have quite a good academic career so far, but I have also taken positions outside of academia when there were no appropriate positions available in my own city.  Consequently, I have become an academic and consultant, with the latter taking over in some periods of my career.

I am mid-career now, and I'm happy with my decision to stay in one place, but there is no doubt that it hampered my ability to advance within academia.  My first two daughters are now all grown up, and I'm really glad I gave priority to my family over my career.  They got to grow-up with their entire extended family in the same city, and they got the benefits of being settled in one place.  For me it has all worked out well.

Comment: "but I have also had positions outside of academia when there were no appropriate positions available in my own city." What?

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, Ben. I've in the past prioritized my career which I don't regret for a second, and has brought me many benefits. But at this stage, I think I want to prioritize other aspects of life like having a family. And personally, staying in academia it's not the most important. I wanted to know that someone out there made a similar decision and does not regret it, thanks for that :) I'm firmly happy on my relationship, and other circumstances led me to apply for the position. And although a really nice project, I'm not ready to sacrifice the steady life we have now.

Comment: @AzorAhai: Not really sure what part of that is unclear.  If you'd like specifics, I took a year out of academia (between two different academic jobs) to work as a data scientist.

Comment: I thought the first "positions" might have meant to be "time periods" or something. Probably it's just a difference in our dialects. I would have found it clearer if it read "I have also taken positions outside of academia when there were no ..."

Comment: @AzorAhai: Okay, I have edited "had" to "taken" to give that formulation.

Answer (score 5):

> I've been thinking about this and if we move he'll suffer the most

This sounds like you haven't talked to him about it.

> and I'm pretty sure it would degrade the relationship.

Why are you so sure?

- It's only for a limited period of time. Assuming your relationship is stable, it's not like he would be forsaking his hometown and family for good.
- Again, you haven't talked to him about how he feels, and what possible ideas he might have for possibly moving for a period of time. You might be surprised.
- If it's a matter of "who needs to adapt more", then perhaps you can strike a different point of balance, involving other aspects of your life together than just the place you live.
- You might be able to arrange, say spending summers back in his hometown (or some other season where you would use up your annual vacation + perhaps take a leave of absence).

I don't have such a story personally, but from my organizational experience, female researchers often give up good post-doc positions to accommodate their male life partners, while vice-versa it's much less common. That's part of the cause for the male-female imbalance of faculty composition at my alma mater and probably many other institutions.

Answer (score 3):

This question is actually much less about academia, and much more about love and relationships.  So while I don't think any of us here have any special expertise in the matter, we might be able to offer the perspective of (mostly older) people who have worked in academia.

In my opinion, this decision is going to be an important turning-point in your life, so you will need to think hard about it.  It is essentially the point at which you decide whether you want to prioritise your career, or prioritise your present relationship at the expense of your career.  There is no doubt that if you are unwilling to move cities, this will restrict your options for an academic career.  In Australia, many early-career academic positions are contract positions, so it can be difficult to get academic jobs that allow you to stay permanently in one place.  This does not mean that it is impossible to stay in your present location (so long as it has a university) but it shrinks your options.  On the other hand, your partner's life and options are important too, so he may have reasons that staying in your present city is better for him.

The reason I say that this will be a turning-point is that your life circumstances and relocations options are likely to get more restricted as you get older.  Since you are early-career (and I am assuming child-free) your options are much broader at the moment.  Indeed, if you have children then you might later find yourself dealing with a "three-body problem" or "four-body problem", etc., instead of a two-body problem.  So you will need to confront this situation now, and think about how you are going to deal with this issue in general.

At the moment you seem to be having only an internal discussion about this, where you speculate on reactions and objections from your partner.  Ultimately, I think you will need to **talk to your partner** and have a wide-ranging discussion on your future.  In particular, it would be useful to think beyond this present job offer and have a broader discussion about your future plans, where you each want to live, how often you are each willing to move (and where), whose career requirements are going to get priority, etc.  This might also be tangled up with other relationship issues --- e.g., are you planning to marry, have children, etc.  It is usually much better to try plan your future to some degree, rather than just stumbling into it via a series of short-term crises and reactive decisions.  (A psychologist might speculate that your story about why you applied for the position is a furphy; that subconsciously you applied because you wanted to get the job and leave, but the story serves as cover to not admit this to yourself.)